# Unable to start envoy in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grpc, envoyproxy, grpc-web

I have this `envoy.yaml`

```
admin:
  access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
  address:
    socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9901 }

static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: listener_0
      address:
        socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 8080 }
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                '@type': type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                codec_type: auto
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: local_service
                      domains: ['*']
                      routes:
                        - match: { prefix: '/' }
                          route:
                            cluster: echo_service
                            timeout: 0s
                            max_stream_duration:
                              grpc_timeout_header_max: 0s
                      cors:
                        allow_origin_string_match:
                          - prefix: '*'
                        allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                        allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout
                        max_age: '1728000'
                        expose_headers: custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_web
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.router
  clusters:
    - name: echo_service
      connect_timeout: 0.25s
      type: logical_dns
      http2_protocol_options: {}
      lb_policy: round_robin
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: cluster_0
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: node-server
                      port_value: 9090
```

This file is copied from this [official example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/tree/master/net/grpc/gateway/examples/echo).

But when I try to go ahead with the [docs](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web#advanced-demo-browser-echo-app)

```
$ docker-compose pull node-server envoy commonjs-client
$ docker-compose up node-server envoy commonjs-client
```

I get this:

`ERROR: No such service: node-server`

if I run `docker-compose pull envoy` I get `ERROR: No such service: envoy`

What did I miss?

Comment: When using docker hub, I can't find the single envoy image you are trying to pull (https://hub.docker.com/search?q=envoy&type=image). So either it's stored in a different (private) docker repo, or it has a different namespace for the image.

Comment: Ok, I am confused as hell now. Thanks! I'll look into this

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I got the wrong assumption in my comments. This repository contains Dockerfiles with a context to create said image when running the docker compose command.
In your example, the command:

```
docker-compose pull node-server envoy commonjs-client
```

should check if the images are available locally. If not, they should be able to build them.

Confusing to me is that you pointed to a `docker-compose.yaml` file stashed away somewhere deep in the examples folder. If you were to run that command I can see why you'd get the error. The relative path to the envoy `Dockerfile` is  `./net/grpc/gateway/docker/envoy/Dockerfile`, which is not accessible from the echo location.
It should however be accessible from your project root (i.e. the directory of this file https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/blob/master/docker-compose.yml). Have you tried running it from there?

Fyi: What should happen after a pull is compose notifying you that the image cannot be found in your local repository and proceeding to create it based on the Dockerfile it found in the path relative to root (`./net/grpc/gateway/docker/envoy/Dockerfile`).